# autocomplete in asp.net mvc (razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement the autocomplete function in my website, but won't work properly.

Here is the code of my view:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#SearchString").autocomplete({
            source: "/Test/AutocompleteSuggestions",
            minLength: 1,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item) {
                    $("#SearchString").val(ui.item.value);
                    $("form").submit();
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{ 
    <p> 
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")   
        <input type="submit" value="Search" /></p> 
}
```

Here is code of my autoComplete controller action:

```
    public JsonResult AutocompleteSuggestions(string searchstring)
    {

      var suggestions = from s in db.Students
                        select s.Name;
      var namelist = suggestions.Where(n => n.ToLower().StartsWith(searchstring.ToLower()));
      // return namelist.ToList();
      return Json(namelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error/behaviour are you experiencing?

Comment: Not really an answer but, you're embedding the `jQuery-ui` script twice (both `dev` and `min`).

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to pass IQueryable. try replacing it with

```
return Json(namelist.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

if that still doesnt work.

try replacing "searchString" to "term"

```
public JsonResult AutocompleteSuggestions(string term)
```

Ive read an article that you must use the "term" query string. but Im not pretty sure about it.